# Como hago para separar fecha y hora que tengo guardado en mi BD en un campo timestamp?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

quiero separar la fecha y hora para mostrarlas por separado,pero la tengo en un campo tipo timestamp estoy ocupando php y mysql

Comment: Bienvenido, deberías leer [ask] y [mcve] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de tu código para tener una idea más precisa de lo que quieres hacer, dado que no se puede entender si lo quieres hacer desde `php` o desde `sql`.

Comment: Puedes crear un objeto de la clase `DateTime` y utilizar el metodo `format` para mostrar la fecha y/o la hora como necesites. Otra opcion podria ser recuperar el dato de mysql con las fonciones de fecha y hora que provee mysql. Igualmente seria recomendable que nos muestres que has intentado o que es lo que tienes exactamente, para de esta forma ayudarte en funcion de lo que tienes.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que pude entender, podrías usar la función `explode` para separar la fecha y la hora, de la siguiente manera:

```
$separar = (explode(" ",$fecha));
```

Previamente a la variable `$fecha` debes asignarle el valor de tu campo *timestamp*.

Esto te creará un arreglo, donde `$separar[0]` equivale a la fecha y `$separar[1]` equivale a la hora.

```
$fecha = $separar[0];
$hora = $separar[1];
```

Comment: He editado tu respuesta para dar formato correcto al código, sugiero que le des clic a _editar_ para que veas tu mismo como se hace (utilizamos [markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Te tengo dos soluciones:

1. Puedes traer separadas la fecha y la hora en columnas de tipo `date` y `time` desde la base de datos, en tu query haz algo como:

   ```
   select   DATE(dateTimeFeild) as Fecha
          , TIME(dateTimeFeild) as Hora
          , col2...
     FROM MiTabla ...
   ```
2. Puedes traer separadas la fecha y la hora en columnas de tipo `char` desde la base de datos, en tu query haz algo como:

   ```
   select   DATE_FORMAT(dateTimeFeild, '%Y-%m-%d') as sFecha
          , DATE_FORMAT(dateTimeFeild,'%H:%i:%s') as sHora
          , col2...
     FROM MiTabla ...
   ```

Comment: Esta sería de acuerdo a lo expuesto la mejor respuesta